# Jquery doing nothing to a certain class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This problem will probably be very simple for anyone that works with JQ. I've just started with the code, so it's not much to look at, really.

```
<table border="1px">     //database connection and <head> with scripts 
    <tr>                    //(including jquery link) come before this
        <th>Data/Timp</th>
        //random headers
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY Timp DESC";
    $result = $conn -> query($sql);
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "
        <tr class = 'mainRow'>
            <td>".$row['Timp']."</td>
            <td>".$row['Tema']."</td>
            //a few more of these
        </tr>";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID_tema = " . $row['ID'];
        echo "<div class = 'dropdown'>";
        $result2 = $conn -> query($sql);
        //more table headers here
        while ($row2 = $result2 -> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "
            <tr>
                <td>".$row2['Timp']."</td>
                <td>".$row2['Descriere']."</td>
                //more of these
            </tr>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

---

What I'm trying to do is something of a questlog, I suppose. You have various *quests* (which you get from a table) and each *quest* has *tasks* which you get from another table. Now the script above works just fine, (even if it's more hideous than Quasimodo), but it does nothing when I try to use Jquery to improve it. What I want to do is click on a *quest* and have the tasks for it slide down or slide back up if they were already expanded. Thing is, my workflow is "Baby steps and check everything works at every point" so the first Jquery I built for it was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
});
```

And, for the life of me, I can't figure why it won't work. Switching to `$('.mainRow').hide();` works just fine, but I don't know how to make that dropdown menu disappear. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Syntaxe to comment html is `<!-- some comment -->` not `//` like php. 
Also, to add classes to an element, the syntaxe is `<div class="some-class">` without spaces around the `=` sign. Hope it helps.

Comment: The comments on the first 2 lines were just so that one could know what came before the part of code I posted, eliminating the need to post the whole thing, so the were added only here, not in the script. It was just a reflex to use '//' rather than '<!--     -->'. Also, from what I've learned (not much, really), html ignores most whitespace, and I've been using spaces before and after each '=' I use and it works. Have I been doing something  wrong?

Comment: No, it's not wrong to use whitespace like you have, it's just that it is a lot more common to connect the terms (as @AdrienLeber has shown above). It makes the HTML easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

For one, you can't embed a `div` inside a table unless you put it inside a `td` element. So in other words the html you're outputting is not correct and that may have an impact

Comment: To hide a group of rows, add the class to each of the <tr>

Comment: The only problem with that is that I can't use $(this).next(.'dropdown') to select exactly what I want to toggle. If I say each row has the dropdown class rather than a group of rows it will either only toggle the first dropdown row or ALL dropdown rows. But I'll figure something out, the problem was indeed the fact that the <div> element was invalid, thanks for the input.

Comment: The power of the almighty Google has revealed unto me the tag of `<tbody>` which can be used to group multiple `<tr>`s in a table. So, for future reference, if, like me, you find yourself needing to group multiple `<tr>`s, use `<tbody>` , not `<div>`.